# jQuery hide and show button using if else

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show-hide

I have a series of tabs in my page, I want to hide the button first off, then when you click on a certain tab within the page - then show the button. This bit I have working!

My problem is - When I click on another tab, I want the to set the button to `hide()` again. Im new to `jQuery` and Im thinking I need to add an `if else` statement to do this?

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.myButton').hide();

    $('a.tab1').click(function() {
        $('.myButton').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('.myButton').hide(); // hide again once clicked off the tab.
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so am assuming you want following with your button.

1. Should not appear, when page loads
2. Should appear only when a certain tab, say tab1 is clicked.
3. Should disappear when anyother tab (other than tab1) is clicked.

then make it simple, change your code to be simple. do this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').hide(0);  //or do it through css
  $('a.tab1').click(function(){
     $('.button').show();

  });

 //otherTab is the class for the tabs other than tab1
 $('a.otherTab').click(function(){
    $('.button').hide();
 });

});
</script>
```

this is a super simple script to achieve what you want. It can be more generic and short. But then you should get the idea right? you should be able to select click events of your respective tabs, that's all you need to sort out.

**Assign Id or Class or whatever to distinctly grab your tabs.**

Answer (score 4):

This code only works when you clic the tab thas has the class `tab1`. Check that all tabs within your page has this class, if not so, assing this class to **all** tabs in your page.

Moreover the function `toggle()` acts as `if` `else` in this case. So if the button is visible `toggle` will make it hidden, else will make it visible:

```
<a class="tab1">tab1</a>
<a class="tab1">tab2</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.myButton').hide();

$('.tab1').click(function() {
  $('.myButton').toggle();
});
});
```

**[TRY IT](http://jsfiddle.net/2LbLp/1/)**

Comment: Added a fiddle to test it. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('div').hide(0);
    $('button').on('click',function(){
    $('div').toggle(200);
    });
});
```

then if you can/would use a fade effect for hiding and showing your element on click you can choose somenthing like ( pretty animation):

```
$(function(){
        $('div').hide(0);
        $('button').on('click',function(){
        $('div').fadeToggle(200);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See `.toggle()` of jQuery.
Has the same of the if statement but managed by jQuery library.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

add click event to the parent of all "tab" links element.

```
$('.parentofTabLinks').click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is('a.tab1'))
        $('.myButton').show();
    else
       $('.myButton').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

keep jquery dom search and don't miss to not keep html link follow

```
var mybutton = $("#mybutton");

$('a.tab_who_show').click(function(event)
{
        mybutton.show();
        event.preventDefault();
});

$('a.tab_who_hide').click(function(event)
{
        mybutton.hide();
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

you can also use jquery.on to work on a container

```
var mybutton = $("#mybutton");
$('#tabs_container').on("click","a.tab_who_hide",function(e){
        mybutton.hide();
        e.preventDefault();
}).on("click","a.tab_who_show",function(e){
        mybutton.show();
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

and test class presence to write a more global code

```
var mybutton = $("#mybutton");
$('#tabs_container').on("click","a",function(e){
        var needToShow = $(this).hasClass('tab_who_show');
        mybutton.toggle(needToShow);
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        // show hide paragraph on button click
        $("p").toggle("slow", function(){
            // check paragraph once toggle effect is completed
            if($("p").is(":visible")){
                alert("The paragraph  is visible.");
            } else{
                alert("The paragraph  is hidden.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```